# Asset Library Not Importing Image Sequence

Tags: asset-browser, image-sequence

I use an image sequence node in order to change character expressions for the robot. I wanted to use the Asset library to import the character on over. But when importing it over using the asset library the image sequence becomes broken. Is there any way to preserve the images in an image sequence node when importing from an asset library?

I had to unlink the image sequence in order to have the image sequence working again.

Comment: In which way does it break?